# How to check if a string contains a sequence of binary regexp chars in postgres

Tags: postgresql, regular-expression, regex

I am trying to filter all non-UTF characters in a field of a table in postgres. It looks to me that I need to filter anything that is not:

```
 $$[\09\0A\0D\x20-\x7E]|$$||               -- ASCII
 $$[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]|$$||             -- non-overlong 2-byte
  $$\xE0[\xA0-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]|$$||        -- excluding overlongs
 $$[\xE1-\xEC\xEE\xEF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|$$||  -- straight 3-byte
  $$\xED[\x80-\x9F][\x80-\xBF]|$$||        -- excluding surrogates
  $$\xF0[\x90-\xBF][\x80-\xBF]{2}|$$||     -- planes 1-3
 $$[\xF1-\xF3][\x80-\xBF]{3}|$$||          -- planes 4-15
  $$\xF4[\x80-\x8F][\x80-\xBF]{2}$$||      -- plane 16
```

Now how can I compare if a string has satisfies regular expression `[\xC2-\xDF][\x80-\xBF]`?

```
select 'ó' ~ '[\xc2-\xdf][\x80-\xbf]' 
select '\xc3\xb3' ~ '[\xc2-\xdf][\x80-\xbf]'
```

return false.

Comment: Is this a bytea column? Seems like a big task.

Comment: it is a varchar, and we managered to enter non-utf8 characters there

Comment: why not just try to convert it?, or dump it, process it with iconv and then reload it.

Comment: because of many postgres servers (distributed environment), and because it is mixed environments (mostly windows), and because it is done on servers we do not have a full access on